# librarian-puppet fails with 'Could not resolve the dependencies.'

Tags: bundler, puppet, librarian-puppet

I have two puppet servers and one is that was setup earlier. Now that i'm trying to get the other server ready and try to run `librarian-puppet install` it fails with `Conflict between puppetlabs-apt (< 3.0.0, >= 2.1.0) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and puppetlabs-apt/1.8.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>`

While the earlier server(production) runs this command fine. The code base is the same. we use same repos.

The Puppetfile:

```
forge 'https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com'

mod 'puppetlabs/stdlib'#, '4.5'
mod 'deric/accounts', '~> 1.0'
mod 'gdsoperations/hosts', '~> 1.0'
mod 'andschwa/unattended_upgrades', '~> 0.1'
mod 'mayflower-php',
 :git => 'https://github.com/stupied4ever/puppet-php',
  :ref => '5e4deee403e31b2dca402b19d961614566e30bfc'
mod 'rodjek/logrotate', '~> 1.1'
mod 'fsalum/newrelic',
  :git => 'https://github.com/fredsmelo/puppet-newrelic',
  :ref => '4_0_4_with_php_custom_options'
 mod 'puppetlabs/mongodb',
   :git => 'https://github.com/<github_user>/puppetlabs-mongodb',
   :ref => '8325d65376a063f726ec653671d19922e8326173'
mod 'thias/sysctl', '~> 1.0'
mod 'erwbgy/limits', '~> 0.3'
mod 'puppetlabs/inifile', '~> 1.2'
mod 'ssm/munin', '~> 0.0.8'
mod 'puppetlabs/haproxy', '~> 1.3'
mod 'garethr/docker', '~> 5.0.0'
mod 'saz/rsyslog', '~>3.5.1'
mod 'jdowning-awscli', '1.3.0'
```

Here is the Puppetfile.lock file:

```
FORGE
  remote: https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com
  specs:
    andschwa-unattended_upgrades (0.2.1)
      puppetlabs-stdlib (>= 1.0.0)
    darin-zypprepo (1.0.2)
    deric-accounts (1.1.3)
      puppetlabs-stdlib (>= 4.2.0)
    erwbgy-limits (0.3.1)
    example42-puppi (2.2.1)
    example42-yum (2.1.28)
      example42-puppi (>= 2.0.0)
    garethr-docker (5.0.0)
      puppetlabs-apt (<= 3.0.0, >= 1.8.0)
      puppetlabs-stdlib (>= 4.1.0)
      stahnma-epel (>= 0.0.6)
    gdsoperations-hosts (1.0.1)
    jdowning-awscli (1.3.0)
      puppetlabs-concat (< 2.0.0, >= 1.0.0)
      puppetlabs-stdlib (< 5.0.0, >= 4.0.0)
      stahnma-epel (< 2.0.0, >= 1.0.0)
    puppetlabs-apt (1.8.0)
      puppetlabs-stdlib (>= 2.2.1)
    puppetlabs-concat (1.2.4)
      puppetlabs-stdlib (< 5.0.0, >= 3.2.0)
    puppetlabs-haproxy (1.3.0)
      puppetlabs-concat (< 2.0.0, >= 1.2.3)
      puppetlabs-stdlib (< 5.0.0, >= 2.4.0)
    puppetlabs-inifile (1.4.2)
    puppetlabs-stdlib (4.5.0)
    rodjek-logrotate (1.1.1)
    saz-rsyslog (3.5.1)
    ssm-munin (0.0.10)
      puppetlabs-stdlib (>= 2.3.0)
    stahnma-epel (1.2.2)
      puppetlabs-stdlib (>= 3.0.0)
    thias-sysctl (1.0.2)

GIT
  remote: https://github.com/fredsmelo/puppet-newrelic
  ref: 4_0_4_with_php_custom_options
  sha: 3fda8416263471253c0228b49a8ed28c9ad2f35e
  specs:
    fsalum-newrelic (4.0.4)
      puppetlabs-apt (>= 1.5.0)
      puppetlabs-stdlib (>= 4.1.0)

GIT
  remote: https://github.com/stupied4ever/puppet-php
  ref: 5e4deee403e31b2dca402b19d961614566e30bfc
  sha: 5e4deee403e31b2dca402b19d961614566e30bfc
  specs:
    mayflower-php (3.4.2)
      darin-zypprepo (~> 1.0)
      example42-yum (~> 2.0)
      puppetlabs-apt (< 3.0.0, >= 1.7.0)
      puppetlabs-inifile (~> 1.0)
      puppetlabs-stdlib (< 5.0.0, >= 4.2.0)

DEPENDENCIES
  andschwa-unattended_upgrades (~> 0.1)
  deric-accounts (~> 1.0)
  erwbgy-limits (~> 0.3)
  fsalum-newrelic (>= 0)
  garethr-docker (~> 5.0.0)
  gdsoperations-hosts (~> 1.0)
  jdowning-awscli (= 1.3.0)
  mayflower-php (>= 0)
  puppetlabs-haproxy (~> 1.3)
  puppetlabs-inifile (~> 1.2)
  puppetlabs-stdlib (>= 0)
  rodjek-logrotate (~> 1.1)
  saz-rsyslog (~> 3.5.1)
  ssm-munin (~> 0.0.8)
  thias-sysctl (~> 1.0)
```

Comment: 1. Please edit your output to only the relevant part. 2. Please share your Puppetfile.

Comment: Can you please tell me why the downvote. so i can correct whats wrong here.

Comment: @MattSchuchard the older server runs `librarian-puppet install` just fine. and it has the same .lock file.

Comment: I can only repeat what the problem is here: you are specifying `puppetlabs/apt` 1.8.0 (confirmed by `.lock`) somewhere and one of your other modules in the dependency hierarchy is requiring >= 2.1.0 (confirmed by error output). There may be a bug in librarian-puppet, but it seems rather unlikely.

Comment: @MattSchuchard If I have not specified `puppetlabs/apt 1.8.0 ` in my Puppetfile anywhere, its being required only by dependencies. Does this mean that the line in Puppetfile.lock:
     `puppetlabs-apt (1.8.0)
          puppetlabs-stdlib (>= 2.2.1)`
is not valid or was added by hand?

Answer (score 1):

The way librarian-puppet parser Puppetfile, metadata.json, Modulefile depends on the puppet version installed on the server.
Please ensure that same version of puppet is installed on both the servers.

If same version of puppet is not installed on both puppet servers then difference in behavior of librarian-puppet for the same Puppetfile is possible.